# I have set a linechart in FXML with scene builder, how can I use it? I shoud add code in controller or main class?

Tags: javafx, fxml

```
<LineChart fx:id="linechart_10mins" layoutY="-78.0" prefHeight="317.0" prefWidth="600.0"  AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="54.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                          <xAxis>
                            <CategoryAxis side="BOTTOM" />                          
                          </xAxis>
                          <yAxis>
                            <NumberAxis side="LEFT" />
                          </yAxis>
                        </LineChart>
```

How can I use this linechart in my code?

Answer (score -1):

Initialize linechart with `@FXML` annotation in your controller, and use your lineChart there for adding and showing data

Comment: Could you please make an example?

Comment: This answer has the wrong annotation.